# Add click event

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I wanna ask about click event in Vue.
I have a span contain div and button. When I click on the button (thisButton) it works well, but the span (thisMask) doesn't seem to work when it clicked. I also add emit event and when I clicked on thisButton it also trigger emit event thisMaskClicked. But the console.log just return which thisButton has. Did I miss something?

```
<span class="this_mask" @click="thisMask">
  <div class="this__wrap">
    <div class="this__text">
      <button class="this__button" @click="thisButton"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

this.js

```
thisMask () {
  this.$emit('thisMaskClicked')
  console.log("This Mask Executed")
},
thisButton() {
  this.$emit('thisButtonClicked')
  console.log("This Button Clicked")
}
```

Comment: `@click=` isn't standard Javascript or HTML. Are you using some sort of templating engine or framework? If so please tag it in your question.

Comment: Yeah, actually I using vuejs @ADyson

Comment: Try `<div>` instead of `<span>`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It still didnt work @StevenSiebert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `self` modifier.

> If a parent node and child node are registered with same type of event then when that type event dispatches then handlers of parent and child are called.

Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9o24m93/)

Your code should look like:

```
<span class="this_mask" @click="thisMask">
  <div class="this__wrap">
    <div class="this__text">
      <button class="this__button" @click.self="thisButton"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Code is untested so I'm not sure if you have to attach in your example to `button` or `span`

Comment: Thank you for answering @null. The fiddle example you attached met my expectations, but when I tried to implement it locally, the click event that used  ```.self``` became unreadable.

Comment: What do you mean with "unreadable"?

Comment: Hi @null actually your solution is working perfectly. Its unreadable because of the style used. Thanks!